# Python Dataframe If Else for every element in Dataframe to create seperate list

Tags: python, pandas

im struggling to find a solution for the following issue,
it's a very simple Code and I guess that's why it's not working properly.
Python keeps throwing These error Messages at me or gives me an Output I didnt not intend to receive.

I am new to Python, so im still learning. Looked up possible solution online, yet I did not find anything that fits my Problem.

I am trying to

- check (if else) for every single element in my dataframe for it's value (I have Doubles only, no String in my dataframe)
- and then add the element in Question to either list A1 or A2
- the dataframe itself I don't want to modify

Approach1:

```
def function103(x):

    if (x > 0):
        A1.append(x)

    else:
        A2.append(x)
return x

# Applying the Code to the dataframe:

df.apply(lambda x: function103(x), axis=1)
```

Dataframe is various in size, at least 1000*3000, so i am Looking for a General way to approach

Approach2:

```
def function103(x):

    if (x > 0).any():
        A1.append(x)

    else:
        A2.append(x)
return x
```

--> gives me a strange list for my A1/A2:

```
 [R1    6.951920e-310
 R2    6.951920e-310
 R3    6.951920e-310
 R4    6.951920e-310
 R5    6.951920e-310
 Name: 2010-09-30T00:00:00.000000000, dtype: float64, Return1    6.951920e-310
 ……..]
```

I dont even think this is considered a list - even though it Closes and opens with These brackets []

I Always reveice this error message:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() (#approach1)
```

And for #approach2 the list im receiving doesn't help at all. I only want the single Elements in said list that meet the If criteria.

Comment: StackOverflow is not for code review. You have to construct your question in a way so your problem is reproducable. In this way: 1. Make a small example dataset and provide it in your question. 2. Describe in words (not in code)  what you want to do. 3. Add an expected output in the form of a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach:

```
x = df[df>0].to_numpy().flatten()
y = df[df<=0].to_numpy().flatten()
A1.extend(x[~np.isnan(x)])
A2.extend(y[~np.isnan(y)])
```

Comment: i like that Approach, too. Thank you for ur answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

[`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) can do this you. It'll apply to function to every cell in the dataframe.

Instead of

```
df.apply(lambda x: function103(x), axis=1)
```

Simply use this

```
df.applymap(function103)
```